# iOS: Getting and displaying album artwork from iPod library

Tags: ios, mpmediaitem

I want to get the album art from a audiobook in the iPod library, But I do not understand how to use `MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork`

```
- (NSArray *)audiobooks
{
    MPMediaPropertyPredicate *abPredicate =
    [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:MPMediaTypeAudioBook]
                                     forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType];

    MPMediaQuery *abQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
    [abQuery addFilterPredicate:abPredicate];
    [abQuery setGroupingType:MPMediaGroupingAlbum];
    NSArray *books = [abQuery collections];
    return books;
}

- (MPMediaItem *)mediaItemForRow: (NSInteger)row
{
    NSArray *audiobooks = self.audiobooks;
    MPMediaItem *mediaItem = nil;

    for (id object in audiobooks) {
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[MPMediaItemCollection class]]) {
            MPMediaItemCollection *book = (MPMediaItemCollection *)object;

            id item = [book items][row];
            if ([item isKindOfClass:[MPMediaItem class]]) {
                mediaItem = (MPMediaItem *)item;

            }
        }
    }
    return mediaItem;
}
```

So now I can get title of media item like this:

```
NSString *title = [mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
```

But how do i get the artwork so I can display it in a UIImage? there is this property:

```
[mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork]
```

I have not managed to find out how to use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not able to get the UIImage from MPMediaItemPropertyArtWork](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604829/not-able-to-get-the-uiimage-from-mpmediaitempropertyartwork)

Comment: Here is a useful reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979013/how-do-i-get-the-album-artwork-of-the-currently-playing-music-using-swift/48035857#48035857

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to fetch the artwork into a UIImage via the following:

```
MPMediaItemArtwork *itemArtwork = [mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
UIImage *artworkUIImage = [itemArtwork imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(64, 64)];
```

In essence, the `MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork` property returns a [MPMediaItemArtwork](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaItemArtwork_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) which you can then obtain a UIImage from.

Comment: Thanks! just as a note the imageWithSize method seems to not resize the image, but instead return fixed size of either 64x64 or 48x48, maybe something to do with my tableView cell, but I don´t think so.

Comment: @TomLilletveit As you imply, I suspect it's the UITableViewCell that's determining the displayed size of the UIImage.

Answer (score 1):

I have just converted the above answer to **Swift 3**:

```
let songInfo: MPMediaItem = self.arrSongs[indexPath.row] as! MPMediaItem
```

// Song Info is Media Item.

```
 let itemArtwork :MPMediaItemArtwork  = songInfo.artwork!
 cell.songImg.image = itemArtwork.image(at: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
```