# Programatically get the name and artist of the currently playing track in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have tried the following:

```
let nowPlaying = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo
```

However I get back `nil` everytime I run it with a song playing.

I would like to be able to grab the track title and artist and display it in my app.

Comment: Here is a useful reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979013/how-do-i-get-the-album-artwork-of-the-currently-playing-music-using-swift/48035857#48035857

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going about this completely the wrong way. MPNowPlayingInfoCenter has nothing to do with learning what is currently playing. If you want to know what the Music app is currently playing, ask the "iPod music player" (in iOS 8, it is called `MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer`).

Comment: Documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/

Answer (score 2):

This is a modified version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61494862).

Using Swift, you can get the Now Playing info, including title, artist, artwork and app on an iOS device using the following private API:

```
// Load framework
let bundle = CFBundleCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework"))

// Get a Swift function for MRMediaRemoteGetNowPlayingInfo
guard let MRMediaRemoteGetNowPlayingInfoPointer = CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName(bundle, "MRMediaRemoteGetNowPlayingInfo" as CFString) else { return }
typealias MRMediaRemoteGetNowPlayingInfoFunction = @convention(c) (DispatchQueue, @escaping ([String: Any]) -> Void) -> Void
let MRMediaRemoteGetNowPlayingInfo = unsafeBitCast(MRMediaRemoteGetNowPlayingInfoPointer, to: MRMediaRemoteGetNowPlayingInfoFunction.self)

// Get song info
MRMediaRemoteGetNowPlayingInfo(DispatchQueue.main, { (information) in
    let bundleInfo = Dynamic._MRNowPlayingClientProtobuf.initWithData(information["kMRMediaRemoteNowPlayingInfoClientPropertiesData"])
    print("\(information["kMRMediaRemoteNowPlayingInfoTitle"] as! String) by \(information["kMRMediaRemoteNowPlayingInfoArtist"] as! String) playing on \(bundleInfo.displayName.asString!)")
})
```

Returns `SONG by ARTIST playing on APP`.

Note this uses the [Dynamic package](https://github.com/mhdhejazi/Dynamic) to easily execute private headers.

This cannot be used in an App Store app due to the use of private API.

Answer (score 1):

try this, if you are writing an iOS app

```
let musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer
if let nowPlayingItem = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem {
    print(nowPlayingItem.title)
} else {
print("Nothing's playing")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an API to get the current playing item information from Music or another app, but to tell the system that your app is currently playing something and give it the information needed to display it on lock screen.

So basically what you're trying to do won't work as you expect it.

Answer (score -3):

Did you set them?

```
var audioPlayer:MPMoviePlayerController=MPMoviePlayerController()

MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo = [
    MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle: "Album Title",
    MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: "Title",
    MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime: audioPlayer.currentPlaybackTime,
    MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration: audioPlayer.duration]
```

The now playing info center supports the following media item property keys:

- `MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle`
- `MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackCount`
- `MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackNumber`
- `MPMediaItemPropertyArtist`
- `MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork`
- `MPMediaItemPropertyComposer`
- `MPMediaItemPropertyDiscCount`
- `MPMediaItemPropertyDiscNumber`
- `MPMediaItemPropertyGenre`
- `MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID`
- `MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration`
- `MPMediaItemPropertyTitle`

Comment: The question is how to Programatically get the name and artist of the currently playing track in swift. This does not answers OP question