# How to get currently playing song on Mac (Swift)

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

On Mac the touch bar can automatically detect what app is playing audio, and lets you play/pause, skip, and even seek through the audio. This works for Spotify, Quicktime, and even websites in your browser, like a YouTube tab on Google Chrome. How can I get the same information (song name, thumbnail, app that's playing the song, duration, etc.) by using Swift?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

macOS has a bunch more system integrations with media players. For example you can ask Siri for the current song or use the Now Playing Today widget:

[image]
[image]

All of these integrations use private APIs in the Media Remote private framework. Since it is a private framework Apple will reject your app if you try to submit it on the Mac App Store. You can still notarize it for distribution outside of the App Store.

To use that framework you can try this:

```
// Load framework
let bundle = CFBundleCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework"))

// Get a Swift function for MRMediaRemoteGetNowPlayingInfo
guard let MRMediaRemoteGetNowPlayingInfoPointer = CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName(bundle, "MRMediaRemoteGetNowPlayingInfo" as CFString) else { return }
typealias MRMediaRemoteGetNowPlayingInfoFunction = @convention(c) (DispatchQueue, @escaping ([String: Any]) -> Void) -> Void
let MRMediaRemoteGetNowPlayingInfo = unsafeBitCast(MRMediaRemoteGetNowPlayingInfoPointer, to: MRMediaRemoteGetNowPlayingInfoFunction.self)

// Get a Swift function for MRNowPlayingClientGetBundleIdentifier
guard let MRNowPlayingClientGetBundleIdentifierPointer = CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName(bundle, "MRNowPlayingClientGetBundleIdentifier" as CFString) else { return }
typealias MRNowPlayingClientGetBundleIdentifierFunction = @convention(c) (AnyObject?) -> String
let MRNowPlayingClientGetBundleIdentifier = unsafeBitCast(MRNowPlayingClientGetBundleIdentifierPointer, to: MRNowPlayingClientGetBundleIdentifierFunction.self)

// Get song info
MRMediaRemoteGetNowPlayingInfo(DispatchQueue.main, { (information) in
    NSLog("%@", information["kMRMediaRemoteNowPlayingInfoArtist"] as! String)
    NSLog("%@", information["kMRMediaRemoteNowPlayingInfoTitle"] as! String)
    NSLog("%@", information["kMRMediaRemoteNowPlayingInfoAlbum"] as! String)
    NSLog("%@", information["kMRMediaRemoteNowPlayingInfoDuration"] as! String)
    let artwork = NSImage(data: information["kMRMediaRemoteNowPlayingInfoArtworkData"] as! Data)

    // Get bundle identifier
    let _MRNowPlayingClientProtobuf: AnyClass? = NSClassFromString("_MRNowPlayingClientProtobuf")
    let handle : UnsafeMutableRawPointer! = dlopen("/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib", RTLD_NOW)
    let object = unsafeBitCast(dlsym(handle, "objc_msgSend"), to:(@convention(c)(AnyClass?,Selector?)->AnyObject).self)(_MRNowPlayingClientProtobuf,Selector("a"+"lloc"))
    unsafeBitCast(dlsym(handle, "objc_msgSend"), to:(@convention(c)(AnyObject?,Selector?,Any?)->Void).self)(object,Selector("i"+"nitWithData:"),information["kMRMediaRemoteNowPlayingInfoClientPropertiesData"] as AnyObject?)
    NSLog("%@", MRNowPlayingClientGetBundleIdentifier(object))
    dlclose(handle)
})
```

Comment: Dang, this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much! I could not find this anywhere else on the internet.

Comment: One more question - is there a way to subscribe to a notification that triggers every time the currently playing media changes? This way I can automatically update my UI.

Comment: @Xenon You need to call `MRMediaRemoteRegisterForNowPlayingNotifications` of type `@convention(c) (DispatchQueue) -> Void` and then subscribe to `kMRMediaRemoteNowPlayingInfoDidChangeNotification` notifications using `NSNotificationCenter`

Comment: Thank you so much! Where can I go to find more information about private API's and MRMediaRemote specifically? There are a lot more things I want to know how to do like playing/pausing and seeking through the time.

Comment: If you can read Objective-C code one place would be one of the apps I'm developing: https://github.com/dimitarnestorov/MusicBar There you will find out how I'm sending commands using Media Remote. There is a tool called `class-dump` that dumps header files from frameworks, however it's only Objective-C classes (no C functions like the ones in my answer). This repo contains dumps for pretty much every recent version: https://github.com/w0lfschild/macOS_headers

Comment: If you want to figure out what kind of C functions are exported by a framework you can use MachOView, but to figure out what kind of parameters a function wants you will have to search the function on Google or start learning reverse engineering and whip out tools like Hopper, Ghidra, and IDA.

Comment: The Mac App store has plenty of apps that show you the currently playing music; e.g., Silicio. What are these apps using then?

Comment: @PeterSchorn These apps communicate with the players individually using ScriptingBridge (AppleScript)

Comment: So it is possible for an app that uses apple script to get accepted to the App Store?

Comment: @PeterSchorn yes

Comment: Trying to access kMRMediaRemoteNowPlayingInfoArtworkData returns me an empty NSData, anyone knows why this could happen?

Comment: @FabrizioBeccaceci does the interface in control center show artwork?

Comment: Yes it does, that's the reason why i think it's weird that the api return empty Data

Comment: Works beautifully, except for some reason that `unsafeBitCast` part crashes for me.

Comment: This works on iOS too, see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74990535/3928858

Comment: Anyone know how to handle the situation where 2 players are playing (ex Spotify + YouTube video at the same time) it only returns informations about the one you interacted with last