# API access to macOS media player information?

Tags: macos

What's the *Kit to get information about current media players and their statuses?

I want to be able to do play/pause of whatever the media player the user is using, but I can't find the APIs or the keywords to search for.

Basically, what's the API version of this thing?
[image: The Mac OSX Media systray menu]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61003379/how-to-get-currently-playing-song-on-mac-swift "All of these integrations use private APIs in the **Media Remote private framework**. Since it is a private framework Apple will reject your app if you try to submit it on the Mac App Store."

Comment: that's exactly the answer i was looking for, thanks @Dai

Answer (score 0):

The keyword I want is "MediaRemote" and is adequately explained in [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61003379/how-to-get-currently-playing-song-on-mac-swift).

It is unfortunately private and not usable by apps submitted to the app store.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to do your own distribution? Apple's App Store (with its arbitrarily and capriciously enforced rules and guidelines) isn't the be-all-all-and-end-all of software for macOS.

Comment: @Dai I'm actually just doing my own thing with pyobjc and global keybinds and an arduino project. I don't care at all about distribution.

Comment: In which case there is nothing stopping you from using the Media Remote library - and I encourage you to continue-on with your project.