# MPMediaItemArtwork is null while cover is available in iTunes

Tags: ios, null, mpmediaitem, cover, artwork

The `UIImage` "image" is always empty ("null") though the cover is shown in the music app by apple.
in iOS 7 it works fine, but with iOS 8 I get no cover.

Whats wrong with my code, or what has changed in iOS 8?

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    AlbumCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AlbumCell"];
    MPMediaItemCollection *song = self.songsList[indexPath.row];

    cell.albumName.text = [[song representativeItem] valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];

    cell.albumArtist.text = [[song representativeItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumArtist];


    CGSize artworkImageViewSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
    MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
    UIImage *image = [artwork imageWithSize:artworkImageViewSize];

    NSLog(@"-------------------");
    NSLog(@"%@",[[song representativeItem] valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle]);
    NSLog(@"%@",image);

    if (artwork) {

        cell.cover.image = image;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.cover.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nocover.png"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

As of iOS 8, `MPMediaItem`'s selector `imageWithSize:(CGSize)size` appears to not guarantee that it will return an image. If no image is returned at the requested size, call it again with the size of the artwork `bounds` property:

```
MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [self valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
UIImage *image = [artwork imageWithSize:size];
if (image == nil) {
    image = [artwork imageWithSize:artwork.bounds.size];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i´ve found the problem.

it´s

```
 CGSize artworkImageViewSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
```

the following works:

```
 CGSize artworkImageViewSize = CGSizeMake(120, 120);
```

or

```
 CGSize artworkImageViewSize = CGSizeMake(60, 60);
```

everything that can be divided by 3 works.

Comment: I think you'll find it's multiples, starting at 60. 60, 120, 240, 360(?), 480....etc. 90 wouldn't work, and 360 wouldn't either.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. I have the same code for getting artwork and it's working for me on iOS 8. Are you SURE the item actually has artwork? Play that song in the music app - artwork?

Comment: yes, when I play the same song or album in the music app, the artwork there.

Comment: artwork != nil BUT image == nil
is there a problem with imageWithSize: ?

Comment: I've tried it in a new project, it does not work, here the project
http://www.file-upload.net/download-9572664/TestCover.zip.html